# Is it possible to edit Sequelize default log?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

When ever a query is executing across a database sequelize is logging to the console like below

> Executing (default): SELECT "user_id", "user_email", "id", "email",
> "start_date", "end_date" FROM "users";

Is there a way that i can edit the word **default** to my **dbname**?
Like

> Executing (dbname): SELECT "user_id", "user_email", "id", "email",
> "start_date", "end_date" FROM "users";

I have multiple db connections running at same time and i want to see the dbname in the log.
Thank you

Comment: Have a look at this https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html#logging

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to edit your logging function to do this.

Comment: Thanks fo the reply, is there an example to go through how to do it?

Comment: see the link in the comment on the q